# Problem creating a python-based app for Mac using py2app

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tkinter, py2app

I created a python app with a user interface (with tkinter and matplotlib) that visualises data from sensors.

It works fine when I compile it into an executable for Windows with pyinstaller.

I am trying to compile it for Mac as well. I am using py2app with the following tutorial: https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

There are no problems with any of those steps, and the app works perfectly on the machine I compiled it on (Macbook Air Early 2014).

I sent the app to three people: one with an older Mac, one with a newer Mac and a colleague with a new Mac. They all say it doesn't run.

On my colleagues laptop I was able to generate the following error by running the app from the command line.

```
Last login: Wed May  3 10:24:38 on ttys000

/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/visualiseSensors ; exit;

(base) iiiman@Imans-MacBook-Air ~ % /Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/visualiseSensors ; exit;

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 89, in _recipes_pil_prescript

    import Image

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 135, in <module>

    _recipes_pil_prescript(['SunImagePlugin', 'DcxImagePlugin', 'Hdf5StubImagePlugin', 'IcnsImagePlugin', 'IcoImagePlugin', 'SgiImagePlugin', 'GbrImagePlugin', 'GifImagePlugin', 'EpsImagePlugin', 'MspImagePlugin', 'PixarImagePlugin', 'FitsImagePlugin', 'BufrStubImagePlugin', 'PalmImagePlugin', 'XpmImagePlugin', 'MpegImagePlugin', 'FpxImagePlugin', 'QoiImagePlugin', 'JpegImagePlugin', 'IptcImagePlugin', 'TiffImagePlugin', 'WmfImagePlugin', 'BmpImagePlugin', 'XVThumbImagePlugin', 'McIdasImagePlugin', 'MpoImagePlugin', 'FliImagePlugin', 'BlpImagePlugin', 'PdfImagePlugin', 'PcdImagePlugin', 'GribStubImagePlugin', 'XbmImagePlugin', 'MicImagePlugin', 'ImtImagePlugin', 'CurImagePlugin', 'PcxImagePlugin', 'DdsImagePlugin', 'ImImagePlugin', 'WebPImagePlugin', 'Jpeg2KImagePlugin', 'PsdImagePlugin', 'FtexImagePlugin', 'FitsStubImagePlugin', 'PpmImagePlugin', 'PngImagePlugin', 'SpiderImagePlugin', 'TgaImagePlugin'])

  File "/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 93, in _recipes_pil_prescript

    from PIL import Image

  File "PIL/Image.pyc", line 103, in <module>

  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "PIL/_imaging.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 343, in load_dynamic

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so' (no such file), '/Users/iiiman/Downloads/GraphicalViewer.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/PIL/_imaging.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))

2023-05-11 11:17:29.054 visualiseSensors[56894:16707595] Launch error

2023-05-11 11:17:29.054 visualiseSensors[56894:16707595] Launch error

See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

It seems something is up with the architecture that it was compiled for, but I'm a bit lost for what to do next. Can anyone help?